# How do i sample an audio file say .wav , specifically import it in an array and divide it in chunks. (in Lua)

Tags: audio, lua, sampling

am not that big on programming and i need to sample an audio file that is recorded via a mobile, i understand that the mobile device records the voice, and there are sample rates and each sample has a 8bit or 16 bit sample size. i need 8 bit sample size in 8khz. the programming environment is lua but that doesnt matter really the basic deal is sampling. Any help would be appreciated. I can get it in 8khz not a problem but how can i get it in an array so that i can divide it hence in short how do i sample an audio .wav file in an array

Answer (score 0):

what format is the audio in? a wav file? if so, you need to read the [RIFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Interchange_File_Format) header.
Then just read the file into an array where each element is a sample.